# Android grid view with custom views

Tags: android

I'm new android development however I've implemented the attached image using UICollectionView in iOS however I want to know if it is possible to implement the same in android.

I've done some initial research regarding grid view as well as the "include" tag.

The tiles are can be shown or hidden depending on variable stored else where.

So am I on the right track?

[image]

Comment: https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need a RecyclerView. This will allow you to have a list. Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) tutorial for the details
2. Each row of the RecyclerView can have the following strucutre

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <TextView
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">
           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">
               <Button 
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
               <Button
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

           </LinearLayout>
           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: I also need it to turn into a two column list on an tablet. Does recycler view still have this capability? I should also mention that the tile components may change depending on the type of information chosen.

Comment: Yes you can do that with RecyclerView. You'd need to listen for orientation change and switch to GridLayoutManager with 2 columns.